# Visual Studio 2008 making substantial changes to line breaks in .rc files

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've recently made a change to a resource file (.rc) in my project using the resource editor, upon committing to SVN I've noted that Visual Studio has merged the longer lines that were originally split between two or more lines into single lines.

While I never edit the .rc file directly and have no interest in what Visual Studio does in there, I do take exception to having to commit a change that appears as if most of the .rc file has changed when in reality I've only changed one menu item. What if another person with different Visual Studio settings come along and the .rc file changes back to the previous arrangement and splits the lines again? We'll have more changes which will basically trash any line by line version control for the file.

Is there a setting somewhere to control this behavour so I only need to change the single in my file without appearing to touch every other long line along the way?

Currently I have to note the change and merge it in manually in a text editor but this is far from ideal, especially when moving to more complicated changes.

I'm hoping it's just a simple option somewhere or if someone can point me to the change in behaviour Microsoft made to Visual Studio 2008 so I know this will be the only big change I'll have to make to the .rc file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no options at all that affect the way the resource editor makes changes to the .rc file.  It sounds to me that the previous programmer that made changes to the file did so with a text editor instead of using the resource editor.

Work this out within your team and agree on a common way to edit.  And tweak your diff tool, many allow ignoring changes to whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Upon further investigation it appears Visual Studio 2003 splits up longer lines in the rc files to ensure the ID constants are all aligned.
Visual Studio 2008 changes this behaviour to ensure everything is all on one single line with no alignment. Considering we shouldn't be editing the .rc with a text editor it makes sense not to bother with the "pretty printing" of the file.